# If $T_{1}\subset T_{2}$ and $T_{1}$ is complete and $T_{2}$ is satisfiable, then $T_{1}= T_{2}$

Tags: proof-writing, satisfiability

If $T_{1}\subset T_{2}$ and $T_{1}$ is complete and $T_{2}$ is satisfiable and both are in the same language , then $T_{1}= T_{2}$

I know a set is complete if $\forall y, y\in T$ or $\neg y\in T$. But I don't know how to apply this towards an actual proof. Can anyone help?

Comment: HINT: $T_1$ is a [maximal consistent](http://planetmath.org/maximallyconsistent) theory. $T_2$ is consistent, since it has a model.

Comment: So you must mean $T_1 \subseteq T_2$

Comment: @Bram28 what would be the difference ?

Comment: $A \subseteq B$ means that $A$ is a subset of $B$, meaning that all elements of $A$ are in $B$. Notice that with this definition, we also have that $A \subseteq A$ for any set $A$: every set is a subset of itself. On the other hand, $A \subset B$ means that $A$ is a *strict* subset of $B$, meaning that (as with any subset) every element of $A$ is in $B$, but there are some elements in $B$ that are not in $A$. So, we never have that $A \subset A$. In your question we are to conclude that $T_1 = T_2$, which is impossible if $T_1 \subset T_2$.